# remove item from laravel session

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.5

Ho to remove array from Session in laravel 5.5?

```
Cart {#228 ▼
  +items: array:2 [▼
    "id_1" => array:8 [▶]
    "id_2" => array:8 [▶]
  ]
  +totalQty: 2
  +totalPrice: 3500
}
```

**In this session i want to remove "id_1"** for example i tryed allready this: `Session::forget('cart.items.' . $id)` where `$id = "id_1"` and it didn't worked.

When i try `dd(Session::get('cart.items')` it returned me `null`...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally figure it out:

```
public function remove($id)
    {
        $cart = Session::get('cart');
        unset($cart->items[$id]);
        Session::put('cart', $cart);

        return back();
    }
```

I hope it will help some one!